# Execute same codes in VBA Excel for 10 seconds but 1 hour in MS Access

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I am trying to transfer codes in Excel (about 200 rows) to MS Access to open the excel files and convert data into two separated files.  It takes only 10 seconds to execute in Excel but 1 hours in MS Access. Both codes are little different but very similar. I'm a newbie to MS Access.

This line below takes very long to perform:
accessDBS.OpenCurrentDatabase rr_full_name

Any thoughts? Thank you!

Below are lines of codes using in Excel and MS Access.

```
Option Compare Database
Dim accessDBS As Access.Application    
Dim db As DAO.Database

Sub opener()
    Dim item
    
    Dim x1 As Excel.Application
    Dim x1wb As Excel.Workbook
    
    Set x1 = New Excel.Application
    Set x1wb = x1.Workbooks.Add
    
    'open access
    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set accessDBS = CreateObject("Access.Application")
    
    x1.Windows(1).Visible = False
    x1wb.Windows(1).Visible = False
    
    'Display a Dialog Box that allows to select a single file.
    'The path for the file picked will be stored in fullpath variable
      With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
            .AllowMultiSelect = True
            'Filter to just the following types of files to narrow down selection options
            .Filters.Add "Excel Files", "*.xlsx, 1"
            '.InitialFileName = ActiveWorkbook.Path
            'Show the dialog box
            .Show
            
            For Each item In .SelectedItems
            Set x1wb = Workbooks.Open(item)
            
            x1wb.Activate
            
            ConvertToCAFTA x1wb, FSO.GetBaseName(x1wb.name), FSO.GetParentFolderName(item)
            x1wb.Close
             
            Next
             
            If .SelectedItems.count = 0 Then
            'debug_panel ("Nothing Selected")
            End If
                  
         End With
             
    accessDBS.Quit
 
End Sub
 
Private Sub ConvertToCAFTA(wkbk As Workbook, orig_name, location)
    Dim Fre_Events As New Collection
    Dim Event_DBS As New Collection
    Dim Gate_DBS As New Collection
    Dim version As Variant
    
    version = "V1.0.4"
    
    
    Dim i, j, count As Variant
    
    i = 1
    'loop through all entries and do custom script for each type
    'each sub will add to the collections which will then be turned into files at the end
    While wkbk.Sheets(1).Cells(i + 1, 1) <> ""
    
    'warning for LogicalValue
    If Lookup("LogicalCondition", i) <> "Normal" And Lookup("Type", i) <> "House Event" Then
    'debug_panel ("CAUTION non Normal Logical Condition Detected - May need manual True/False FTA review")
    End If
    
    Select Case Lookup("Type", i)
    
    Case "Basic Event", "Undeveloped Event"
    Basic_Database i, Event_DBS
    
    Case "Remarks Gate"
        'special case since it can have either 0 or multiple sub gates
        j = 1
        count = 0
        While wkbk.Sheets(1).Cells(j + 1, 1) <> ""
        If Lookup("ParentID", j) = Lookup("Identifier", i) Then
        count = count + 1
        End If
        j = j + 1
        Wend
        
        If count = 0 Then
        Basic_Database i, Event_DBS
        ElseIf count = 1 Then
        Gate i, Fre_Events
        Gate_Database i, Gate_DBS
        Else
        'debug_panel ("WARNING more than one sub gate branching to a remarks gate")
        End If
    
    Case "Transfer-In Gate"
    'do nothing
    
    Case "OR Gate"
    Gate i, Fre_Events
    Gate_Database i, Gate_DBS
    
    Case "AND Gate"
    Gate i, Fre_Events
    Gate_Database i, Gate_DBS
    
    Case "House Event"
    Basic_Database i, Event_DBS
    
    Case "Voting Gate"
    Gate i, Fre_Events
    Gate_Database i, Gate_DBS
    
    Case Else
    'debug_panel ("unknown gate type for " & CStr(i + 1))
    End
    
    End Select
    
    i = i + 1
    Wend
    
    clear_duplicates Event_DBS
    clear_duplicates Gate_DBS
    clear_duplicates Fre_Events
    
    'output the FRE
    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    
    Set text_file = FSO.CreateTextFile(location & "\" & orig_name & "_" & Replace(Date, "/", "_") & "_" & version & "_FTA.fre", True)
    
    Dim item As Variant
    For Each item In Fre_Events
    text_file.WriteLine (item)
    Next
    text_file.Close
    
    'create database
    Dim DBS As Database
    Dim dbs_name
    rr_full_name = location & "\" & orig_name & "_" & Replace(Date, "/", "_") & "_" & version & "_DBS.rr"
    FSO.CopyFile location & "\CAFTA_TemplateV1_0_4.rr", rr_full_name, True
    accessDBS.OpenCurrentDatabase rr_full_name
    Set DBS = accessDBS.CurrentDb
    
    For Each item In Event_DBS
    DBS.Execute "INSERT INTO BE VALUES(" & item & ")"
    Next
    
    For Each item In Gate_DBS
    DBS.Execute "INSERT INTO GT VALUES(" & item & ")"
    Next
    
    DBS.Close
    accessDBS.CloseCurrentDatabase


End Sub


Private Function Lookup(Identifier As Variant, Record_Num As Variant) As Variant
    Dim row, col, i, j
    row = 0
    col = 0
    'Find matching column
    i = 1
    While Sheets(1).Cells(1, i) <> "" And col = 0
    If Identifier = Sheets(1).Cells(1, i) Then
    col = i
    End If
    
    i = i + 1
    Wend

    row = CVar(Record_Num) + 1
    'output value
    Lookup = Sheets(1).Cells(row, col)

End Function
```

Comment: If the performance is such different, what ist the different in the code? What is such slow (try to implement a logging)? I guess your _Lookup_ is slow (why don't you use a excel function there)

Comment: Hi Shrotter,  how can I improve my Lookup function?  What do you mean about an excel function?  Thank you!

Comment: In your Lookup function there is no exit statement if a specific value is found so the while loop is not stopped in advance. Maybe this function can be replaced by `WorksheetFunction.Lookup`. I suggest you to test with logging/debug.print which part of your complete macro is slow.

Comment: Shrotter - I stepped thru and this line accessDBS.OpenCurrentDatabase rr_full_name takes very long to pass.  Lookup function is fine.

Comment: How big is the database you are opening? I'm not familiar with Access, maybe it is faster to write into the database without opening it in access (see ADO)

Comment: Thank you!  I fixed the database issues, and it takes 12 mins instead of 60 mins.  Access does not have worksheetFunction.Lookup.  Excel version only takes 20 seconds to execute.